# Centering 2 elements inside Bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So if i have only one element, in my case a button, i just add the `.center-block` class to that element and it is centered.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Element 1</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But what if i have two elements? I tried to wrap them in a div and added a `.center-div` class like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <div class="center-div">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Element 1</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Element 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.center-div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

`.center-div` is almost the same as `.center-block` except that i used `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;` so that it fits the contents size.

Sadly it doesn't work. Unless i change it to `display: block;` and assing it a fixed width like 200px.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin right and left set to auto only works if the width of the element is fixed.
As your `center-div` is now an inline-block, you need a `text-align: center` property on its container.

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <div class="center-div">
        <!-- inner elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

*I used a style attribute for convenience in this example*

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps:

```
.center-div {
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
body{
text-align: center;
}
```